# use of extern methods between dll projects?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, extern

I have a debug condition to manage memory where I have

```
    extern void* operator new(unsigned int size, const char* file, int line);
    extern void operator delete(void* address, const char* file, int line);
    extern void Delete(void* address);
    #define FUN_NEW new(__FILE__, __LINE__)
    #define FUN_DELETE delete
```

This exists in **Memory.h** and is implemented in **Memory.cpp**.  Memory.h is defined as:

```
#ifdef MEMORY_EXPORT
#define DECL_MEMORY __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECL_MEMORY __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
class DECL_MEMORY Memory : public Singleton<Memory>
{
```

Now, I have **SoundStuff.h** and **SoundStuff.cpp**, which are in a seperate project, also being converted to a dll in a similar manner to above.  The project that `SoundStuff` belongs to has a project dependency to the project that `Memory` belongs to.  In the implementation of SoundStuff.cpp, `FUN_DELETE`, from **Memory.h**, is called.  It is called through a function in a separate project, but it is called regardless.  This is leading to linker errors.

> error LNK2019: unresolved external
>   symbol "void __cdecl operator
>   delete(void *,char const *,int)"
>   (??3@YAXPAXPBDH@Z) referenced in
>   function
>   __unwindfunclet$?Init@SoundStuff@@AAEXXZ$1    SoundStuff.obj

Why is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Please show how you link CoreFunctions to DoSomeStuff.

Comment: Added to description.  There is a project dependency there and the Init function of a class in DoSomeStuff calls FUN_DELETE, which is defined in CoreFunctions

Comment: Thanks. One other bit; you say: "It is called through a function in a separate project" - can you clarify what this means in that case? Do you mean that `SoundStuff.cpp` calls a function in some other project, which in turn calls `FUN_NEW`? If so, does the code in that other project also do `#include "Memory.h"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly tell the compiler which functions you'd like to export.  There's a little song-and-dance to do this, here's how I do it:

```
#ifdef USING_DLL
#ifdef CORE_EXPORTS
#define CORE_EXPORT __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define CORE_EXPORT __declspec( dllimport )
#endif
#else
#define CORE_EXPORT
#endif
```

Each function (or class) I would like to export gets tagged with `CORE_EXPORT`.  To build for DLLs, define `USING_DLL`, and in your CoreFunctions project (but not your DoSomeStuff project) define `CORE_EXPORTS`.  That will ensure that your functions/classes are declared `__declspec( dllexport )` when the CoreFunctions DLL is building (so they are exported), and `__declspec( dllimport )` when DoSomeStuff is building (so they are imported).

Comment: This is true, sorry for not specifying this.  I ahve done this.  I have labelled absolutely every class with this macro

Comment: So what do your function prototypes actually look like?

Comment: Or are those functions part of a class declaration?

Comment: I've added what I believe you are asking for

Comment: If the new and delete are not class members, you need to add `DECL_MEMORY` to them, too.  Like this:

`DECL_MEMORY void* operator new(unsigned int size, const char* file, int line);`

Comment: (I never use extern like you are using it, not sure if there is a point to that or not.)